# MongoDB - advanced query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to perform a query to my MongoDB to find a car document that matches an `_id` for one of `myCars`. Say I would want to perform some update on that document and I would like to do so in one query. But I really want to make sure that the car document also matches the `color` of my car before performing the update. Is there any way to do this in a single query?

```
const myCars = [
    { _id: "abc", color: "Red" },
    { _id: "def", color: "Blue" },
];

Car.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: {
        $in: myCars.map(car => car._id),
    },
    color: myCars -->[?]<--.color,   // the car that matched the $in operator
}, {...});
```

I'm not sure what the proper keywords would be of this question but I'll make sure to update the title when I get some clarity!

Answer (score 0):

You could try an `[$or][1]` query that would use a list of expressions that match for each of cars in your `myCars` arrays. Assuming that `myCars` is an array of objects with only `_id` and `color` fields:

```
Car.findOneAndUpdate({$or: myCars})
```

*double check my assumption though*

Imho using `$or` is usually a good indicator that some refactoring could be done elsewhere, so you might also try to approach your specific problem from a new angle. Especially if that `myCars` array is large or your data set is very large. According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes), an "or query" can perform an index scan if both fields are indexed.